# D3 chart and external json data

Tags: api, d3.js, real-time, linechart

I’m making a D3 line chart. It works fine if I'm loading the data from a JSON inside a variable ([link here](https://codepen.io/krissy20/pen/veQQNR)). However, when I pull the same data live from a web API and add these lines to my code:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        makeChart(data);
    }

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
        d.size = +d.size;
    });
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
    });

    makeChart(data);
  }
);
```

I get an error message “Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function” ([see here](https://codepen.io/krissy20/pen/RLqqKB)). My 2 axes get rendered but the line doesn't. 
The format of my data is like this:

```
{
query: {
  usercontribs: [
    {
      size: 761,
      timestamp: "2017-07-17T21:00:25Z"
    },
    {
      size: 540,
      timestamp: "2016-11-29T02:06:28Z"
    }
   ]
  }
};
```

Please could anyone have a look and explain how I could fix that? I've been struggling with it for several days and would welcome some help. Thank you!

Comment: Its because  `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php` has not allowed cross origin.
so may be you can host your json in gist and access.

Comment: That is because `data` is actually an object. If you want to loop through the array embedded in it, you will have to do `data.query.usercontribs.forEach(...)`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post, people have taken time to answer it.

Comment: I've rolled back to @PetterFriberg's revision. Please do not blank your question, it may be of help to others in the future. If the answer below helped, please accept it by clicking the ✓ icon below the score.

Comment: **Do not vandalise your post**. If you no longer want a post to be associated with your account, you can [request post disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0).

Comment: For the umpteenth time, please **do not vandalize your post** cc:@MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1):

Lot of issues:

1) you should set your data for the response `data = data.query.usercontribs;`

2) Convert the time stamp to date object

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.timestamp = new Date(parseDate(d.timestamp));
    d.size = +d.size;
  });
```

3) This is completely incorrect.

```
if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        makeChart(data);
    }
    //you have already called makechart in the else! 
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
        d.size = +d.size;
    });
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
    });

    makeChart(data);
```

should have been:

```
d3.json(
  "URL",
  function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      data = data.query.usercontribs;
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = new Date(parseDate(d.timestamp));
        d.size = +d.size;
      });
      data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
      });

      makeChart(data);
    }
  }
);
```

working code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boOavw?editors=0010)